# Unexpected return value ^M from getchar / putchar when reading a file

Tags: c

I'm working with text formatting using getchar and putchar (from Ritchie C book).  I am able to eliminate '//' comments but am having trouble removing some of the newlines on blank lines.  I want to eliminate line comments '//' and "blanK" newlines - lines without any text - from the source file.

I'm getting weird ^M characters in the output file.

It seems the if else statement that checks if the previous char (pre) and the current char c are both '\n' is creating the error.

If you remove this it no longer gives weird output:

```
else if(c == '\n' && pre == '\n')
{
    pre = c;
}
```

Full code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>


main()
{
int c;
int pre;
int comment = 0;

while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
{
    // printf("%c", c);
    // printf("pre is %c comment is %d c is %c\n", pre, comment, c);   
    // check to see if we're at a newline and set comment toggle to 0        
    if(c == '\n' && comment ==1)
    {
        comment = 0;
        pre = c;
    }
    else if(c == '\n' && pre == '\n')
    {
        pre = c;
    }
    else if(comment == 1)
    {
        pre = c;
    }
    else if(pre == '/' && c == '/')
    {
        comment = 1;
        pre = c;
    }
    else if(c == '/')
    {
        pre = c;
    }
    else if(pre =='/')
    {
        putchar(pre);
        putchar(c);
        pre = c;
    } 
    else
        putchar(c);
}
return 0;
}
```

Input file is Add.asm.

```
// This file is part of www.nand2tetris.org
// and the book "The Elements of Computing Systems"
// by Nisan and Schocken, MIT Press.
// File name: projects/06/add/Add.asm

// Computes R0 = 2 + 3  (R0 refers to RAM[0])

@2
D=A
@3
D=D+A
@0
M=D
```

Output file is bdd.hack, it looks fine on github but when I open with vim it looks like this:

```
^M^M@2^MD=A^M@3^MD=D+A^M@0^MM=D
```

C program is assembler.c. 
I'm calling this on the command line like this
cc assembler.c
./a.out bdd.hack

[github repo with input file Add.asm, output file bdd.hack, and program to format text assembler.c](https://github.com/theporpoise/assembler)

NOTE: this is for a self study course NAND to tetris - I'm writing this in C b/c I'm learning C and thought this would be a fun project to do in C (a basic assembler).  You can ignore the psuedo  code at the bottom of assembler.c.

Comment: Please don't post links to code. Post the code instead. See [ask].

Comment: ^m is a carriage return... On windows text file lines end with Carriage Return, followed by a linefeed... you should strip both

Comment: @TonyB I'm currently running debian on a virtual box on windows 10.  would this affect me if I'm running Debian on a virtual box?

Comment: hexdump your input file and look at its contents... (or you can look at it using bvi (Binary VI ) ).

Comment: @TonyB you were right!  it was a windows text file.  I used dos2unix and problem solved.  Thank you - I was stuck there.  really appreciate it!

Comment: if the input file contains any blank lines, then the sequence '\n', '\n' will be found

Comment: there are only 2 valid signatures for the function `main()`  they are: `int main( void )` and `int main( int, char** )`   Notice that they all have a return type of `int`.  Modern C (except for visual studio which is way behind) do not assume a `int` return type nor that parameters are `int`

Comment: this command line: `cc assembler.c ./a.out bdd.hack` will not pass the contents of `bdd.hack` to stdin of the C program.  Suggest: `cc assembler.c ./a.out < bdd.hack`  Also suggest separating the two command strings in such a manner that if the compile fails, the `a.out` file is not executed

Answer (score 0):

It was a windows text file and therefore had ^M characters as suggested by TonyB above. I used dos2unix to format the file correctly on my debian system and the problem was solved. Thank you everyone for your help!